# Installing triggers on AppMaker deployment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

When I deploy my AppMaker app to a deployment, I'd like to execute some code to automatically install the relevant triggers.

Is there a way to install triggers when the app is deployed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [App Startup](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/settings#app_start) option to run some logic when the app starts. Maybe use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to save a property that contains a value indicating if the triggers have been installed or not and everytime that the app starts, check if the triggers are installed and take action based on that.